# NoSuchElementException: M no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/table"}

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the table with all ISIN codes from [following](http://stockcare.net/ISINNumber.asp) website, but I'm getting Error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/table"}
```

**Code**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = r"C:\Users\HP\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('http://stockcare.net/ISINNumber.asp')
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table')
print(table)
driver.quit()
```

As I get the table I want to store it into the pandas DataFrame. Can someone help me out?

Comment: try adding some delay to it

Comment: Are you sure that there is a table that is the child of form? Did you mean `'/html/body/table'` or `'//form//table'`?

Comment: @JaSON I have taken copy selector from inspect element so it should be correct!

Comment: @noob_big_data the table you are trying to access is inside a frame. You need to switch to the frame and do find_element.

Comment: @GhostOps tried man still it remains same

Comment: @itronic1990 can you suggest tutorial link, that would have been great help!

Comment: @noob_big_data Checkout the suggested links within my answer

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To print the table data as the elements are within an `<iframe>` you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be visible*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("http://stockcare.net/ISINNumber.asp")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"form[name='frmScrip'] iframe")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[name='frmDetails']"))).text)
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Group BSE Code BSE Name ISINNO Old Name
  A 523395 3M India Ltd INE470A01017 Birla 3m
  A 524348 Aarti Drugs INE767A01016
  A 524208 Aarti Ind(5) INE769A01020
  A 541988 Aavas Financiers INE216P01012
  A 500002 Abb India Ltd.(2) INE117A01022 Abb Ltd.(2)
  A 543187 ABB Power Prod(2) INE07Y701011
  A 500488 Abbott (I) Ltd INE358A01014 Knoll Pharm.
  A 500410 ACC INE012A01025
  A 532762 Action Const(2) INE731H01025
  A 512599 Adani Enter(1) INE423A01024
  A 541450 Adani Green Energy INE364U01010
  A 532921 Adani Ports(2) INE742F01042 Mundra Port
  A 519183 ADF Foods Ltd INE982B01019 American Dry
  A 535755 Adi.Bir.Fash INE647O01011 Pantaloons F
  A 540691 Adit.Bir.Capital INE674K01013
  A 540025 Advanced Enzym(2) INE837H01020
  A 500003 Aegis Logist(1) INE208C01025
  A 542752 Affle(India)(2) INE00WC01027
  A 500215 Agro Tech Food INE209A01019 ITC Agro-tec
  A 532811 Ahluwalia Co(2) INE758C01029
  A 532683 Aia Engineer(2) INE212H01026
  A 532331 Ajanta Pharma(2) INE031B01049
  A 500710 Akzo Nobel India INE133A01011 ICI India
  A 506235 Alembic Ltd(2) INE426A01027
  A 533573 Alembic Pha(2) INE901L01018
  A 539523 Alkem Laborat(2) INE540L01014
  A 506767 Alkyl Amines(2) INE150B01039
  A 532480 Allahabad Bk INE428A01015
  A 532749 Allcargo Logis(2) INE418H01029 Allcargo Glo
  A 500008 Amar Raja B(1) INE885A01032
  A 540902 Amber Enterp.India INE371P01015
  A 500425 Ambuja Cem(2) INE079A01024
  A 532418 Andhra Bank INE434A01013
  A 532259 Apar Ind. INE372A01015
  A 523694 Apcotex Indus(2) INE116A01032
  A 540692 Apex Frozen Foods INE346W01013
  A 533758 APL Apollo Tub(2) INE702C01027
  A 508869 Apollo Hosp.(5) INE437A01024
  A 531761 Apollo Pipes Ltd INE126J01016
  A 538566 Apollo Tricoat Tu(2) INE919P01029 Best Steel L
  A 500877 Apollo Tyre(1) INE438A01022
  A 532475 Aptech Ltd INE266F01018 Aptech Train
  A 531179 Arman Fin.Serv. INE109C01017 Arman Leasin
  A 542484 Arvind Fashion (4) INE955V01021
  A 500101 Arvind Ltd INE034A01011 Arvind Mills
  A 515030 Asahi Ind Gl(1) INE439A01020
  A 500477 Ashok Leyland(1) INE208A01029
  A 533271 Ashoka Buildcon(5) INE442H01029
  A 532888 Asian Granito INE022I01019
  A 500820 Asian Paint(1) INE021A01026
  A 533138 Astec Lifesci INE563J01010
  A 540975 Aster DM Healthcare INE914M01019
  A 532493 Astra Micro(2) INE386C01029
  A 532830 Astral Ltd(1) INE006I01046 Astral Poly(
  A 506820 Astrazen.Ph(2) INE203A01020 Astra Idl
  A 500027 Atul Ltd. INE100A01010
  A 540611 AU Small Finan Bank INE949L01017
  A 524804 Aurobindo Ph(1) INE406A01037
  A 539289 Aurum Proptech Ltd(5 INE898S01029 Majesco Ltd(
  A 505010 Auto Axles INE449A01011
  A 512573 Avanti Feeds(1) INE871C01038
  A 540376 Avenue Supermarts INE192R01011
  A 532215 Axis Bank (2) INE238A01034
  A 532977 Bajaj Auto Ltd INE917I01010
  A 533229 Bajaj Consumer Ca(1) INE933K01021 Bajaj Corp(1
  A 500031 Bajaj Elec(2) INE193E01025
  A 500034 Bajaj Finance(2) INE296A01024
  A 532978 Bajaj Finvest(5) INE918I01018
  A 500032 Bajaj Hind Sugar(1) INE306A01021 Bajaj Hindus
  A 500490 Bajaj Hold&Inves INE118A01012 Bajaj Auto
  A 530999 Balaji Amine(2) INE050E01027
  A 532382 Balaji Tele(2) INE794B01026
  A 502355 Balkrish Ind(2) INE787D01026
  A 523319 Balmer Lawri INE164A01016
  A 500038 Balrampur Chi(1) INE119A01028
  A 541153 Bandhan Bank Ltd INE545U01014
  A 532525 Bank Maharashtra INE457A01014
  A 532134 Bank of Baroda(2) INE028A01039
  A 532149 Bank of India INE084A01016
  A 500041 Bannari Aman INE459A01010
  A 500042 Basf India INE373A01013
  A 500043 Bata India(5) INE176A01028
  A 506285 Bayer Corp INE462A01022 Bayer India
  A 500048 BEML Ltd INE258A01016 Bh.Earth Mov
  A 509480 Berger Paint(1) INE463A01038
  A 533303 BF Investment Ltd INE878K01010
  A 532430 BF Utilities(5) INE243D01012
  A 500052 Bhansali Eng(1) INE922A01025
  A 503960 Bharat Bijle(10) INE464A01028
  A 541143 Bharat Dynamics INE171Z01018
  A 500049 Bharat Elec(1) INE263A01024
  A 533228 Bharat Financial INE180K01011 SKS Microfin
  A 500493 Bharat Forge(2) INE465A01025
  A 500103 Bharat heavy(2) INE257A01026
  A 500547 Bharat Petro INE029A01011
  A 532454 Bharti Artl(5) INE397D01024
  A 532523 Biocon Ltd(5) INE376G01013
  A 500335 Birla Corp INE340A01012
  A 532400 BirlaSoft Ltd(2) INE836A01035 Kpit Technol
  A 506197 Bliss Gvs Ph(1) INE416D01022 Bliss Chem
  A 526612 Blue Dart Ex INE233B01017
  A 500067 Blue Star(2) INE472A01039
  A 524370 Bodal Chem(2) INE338D01028 Dintex Dye
  A 501425 Bombay Burmah(2) INE050A01025
  A 500020 Bombay Dyeing(2) INE032A01023
  A 502219 Borosil Renewable INE666D01022 Borosil Glas
  A 500530 BOSCH LTD INE323A01026 Motor ind
  A 532929 Brigade Enterpr INE791I01019
  A 500825 Britania Ind(1) INE216A01030
  A 532321 Cadila Health(1) INE010B01027
  A 532834 Camlin Fine Sc(1) INE052I01032
  A 532483 Canara Bank INE476A01014
  A 511196 Canfin Homes(2) INE477A01020
  A 524742 Caplin Point(2) INE475E01026
  A 531595 Capri Global Capi INE180C01018 Money Mat Fi
  A 513375 Carborundum(1) INE120A01034
  A 534804 CARE Ratings Ltd INE752H01013 Credit Analy
  A 500870 Castrol Ind(2) INE172A01027
  A 519600 CCL Products(2) INE421D01022
  A 500878 Ceat Limited INE482A01020
  A 532885 Central Bank INE483A01010
  A 500040 Century INE055A01016
  A 532548 Centuryply(1) INE348B01021
  A 532443 Cera Sanitar(5) INE739E01017 Madhusudan O
  A 500084 CESC Ltd.(1) INE486A01021
  A 542399 Chalet Hotels Ltd INE427F01016
  A 500085 Chambal Fert INE085A01013
  A 500110 Chennai Pet. INE178A01016 Madras Ref.
  A 511243 Chola.Inv&fin(2) INE121A01024
  A 504973 Cholamandalam Fin(2) INE149A01025 TI Fin.Holdi
  A 534758 Cigniti Techno INE675C01017 Chakkilam In
  A 500087 Cipla Ltd(2) INE059A01026
  A 532210 City Union Bnk(1) INE491A01021
  A 506390 Clariant Chem INE492A01029 Colour Chem
  A 533278 Coal India Ltd INE522F01014
  A 540678 Cochin Shipyard INE704P01017
  A 532541 Coforge Ltd INE591G01017 NIIT Tech
  A 500830 Colgate Palm(1) INE259A01022 Colgate
  A 531344 Contain.Corp(5) INE111A01025
  A 506395 Coromand.Inter(1) INE169A01031 Coromand.Fer
  A 532179 Corpn.Bank(2) INE112A01023
  A 508814 Cosmo Films INE757A01017 Cosmo Fil(pr
  A 541770 Credit Access Grameen INE741K01010
  A 500092 CRISIL Rating(1) INE007A01025
  A 539876 Crompt.Grev.Cons(2) INE299U01018
  A 542867 CSB Bank Ltd INE679A01013
  A 500480 Cummins Ind(2) INE298A01020 Kirlos.cumm
  A 532175 Cyient Ltd(5) INE136B01020 Infotech Ent
  A 500096 Dabur India(1) INE016A01026
  A 500097 Dalmia Bhar.Sug(2) INE495A01022 Dalmia Cemen
  A 542216 Dalmia Bharat Ltd INE00R701025 Odisha Cemen
  A 533151 DB CORP LTD INE950I01011
  A 532772 DCB Bank Ltd INE503A01015 Dev Cred ban
  A 523367 Dcm Shriram Ltd(2) INE499A01024 Dcm Shriram
  A 500645 Deepak Fert. INE501A01019
  A 506401 Deepak Nitrit(2) INE288B01029
  A 532848 Delta Corp (1) INE124G01033 Arrow Webtex
  A 533137 Den Networks Ltd INE947J01015
  A 532121 Dena Bank INE077A01010
  A 519588 DFM Foods(2) INE456C01020
  A 500119 Dhampur Suga INE041A01016
  A 507717 Dhanuka Agrit(2) INE435G01025 Dhanuka Pest
  A 540047 Dilip Buildcon INE917M01012
  A 540701 Dishman Carbogen Amics INE385W01011
  A 532488 Divi's Lab.(2) INE361B01024
  A 540699 Dixon Techno(2) INE935N01020
  A 532868 Dlf Ltd(2) INE271C01023
  A 541403 Dollar Indus.(2) INE325C01035
  A 539524 DR Lal Pathlabs INE600L01024
  A 500124 DR Reddys Lab(5) INE089A01023
  A 523618 Dredging Cor INE506A01018
  A 532610 Dwarkes Sugar(1) INE366A01041
  A 532927 Eclerx Serv.Ltd INE738I01010
  A 532922 Edelweiss Fin(1) INE532F01054 Edelweiss Ca
  A 505200 Eicher Motor(1) INE066A01021
  A 500125 Eid Parry(1) INE126A01031
  A 500840 Eih Ltd(2) INE230A01023
  A 500123 Elantas Beck In INE280B01018 Schenec.Beck
  A 522074 Elgi Equipment(1) INE285A01027
  A 531162 Emami Ltd(1) INE548C01032 Himani Ltd.
  A 540153 Endurance Tech. INE913H01037
  A 532178 Engineers(i)(5) INE510A01028
  A 500135 EPL Limited(2) INE255A01020 Essel Propp(
  A 539844 Equitas Holdings INE988K01017
  A 540596 Eris Lifescienc(1) INE406M01024
  A 500133 Esab India INE284A01012
  A 500495 Escorts Ltd INE042A01014
  A 531508 Eveready Ind(5) INE128A01029
  A 500650 Excel Ind.(5) INE369A01029
  A 500086 Exide Ind(1) INE302A01020 Chloride Ltd
  A 531599 Fdc Ltd(1) INE258B01022
  A 505744 Fed Mog Goetze INE529A01010 Goetze India
  A 500469 Federal Bank(2) INE171A01029
  A 541557 Fine Organic Indus. INE686Y01026
  A 500144 Finolex Cabl(2) INE235A01022
  A 500940 Finolex Ind.(2) INE183A01024
  A 532809 Firstsource Solut INE684F01012
  A 500033 Force Motor INE451A01017
  A 532843 Fortis Healthcare INE061F01013
  A 533400 Future Consum.(6) INE220J01025 Future Consu
  A 536507 Future Lifestyl(2) INE452O01016
  A 540064 Future Retail Lt(2) INE752P01024
  A 505714 Gabriel Ind(1) INE524A01029
  A 532155 Gail (I) Ltd INE129A01019
  A 540935 Galaxy surfactants INE600K01018
  A 542011 Garden Reach ShipBld INE382Z01011
  A 509557 Garware Technical INE276A01018 Garware Wall
  A 532622 Gateway Dist INE852F01015
  A 532345 Gati Ltd(2) INE152B01027 Gati Corpn.
  A 532309 GE Power India Lt INE878A01011 Alstom India
  A 500620 GE Shiping INE017A01032
  A 522275 GE T&D India(2) INE200A01026 Alstom T&D (
  A 540755 General Insur.Corp(5) INE481Y01014
  A 500173 GFL Ltd(1) INE538A01037 Guj.Flouro(1
  A 511676 GIC Housing INE289B01019
  A 507815 Gillette Ind INE322A01010 Ind.Shaving
  A 500660 Glaxo Ltd. INE159A01016
  A 500676 Glaxosmithkl INE264A01014 Smithkl.Co
  A 532296 Glenmark Phar(1) INE935A01035
  A 505255 Gmm Pfaudler(2) INE541A01023 Guj.Machine
  A 532754 Gmr Infrastr(1) INE776C01039
  A 500163 Godfrey Phil(2) INE260B01028
  A 540743 Godrej Agrovet INE850D01014
  A 532424 Godrej Consum(1) INE102D01028
  A 500164 Godrej Indus(1) INE233A01035 Godrej Soaps
  A 533150 Godrej Propert(5) INE484J01027
  A 500168 Goodyear (I) INE533A01012
  A 532482 Granules(i)(1) INE101D01020
  A 509488 Graphite Ind(2) INE371A01025 Carbon Everf
  A 500300 Grasim Ind.(2) INE047A01021
  A 501455 Greaves Cotton(2) INE224A01026 Greaves Ltd.
  A 526797 Greenply Ind(1) INE461C01038
  A 506076 Grindwell Nort(5) INE536A01023
  A 511288 Gruh Finance(2) INE580B01029
  A 530001 Guj.Alkali INE186A01019
  A 524226 Guj.Amb.Exp(1) INE036B01030
  A 500171 Guj.H.Chem INE539A01019
  A 517300 Guj.Ind.Pow. INE162A01010
  A 532181 Guj.Mineral(2) INE131A01031
  A 500670 Guj.Narmada INE113A01013
  A 532702 Guj.Petronet INE246F01010
  A 500690 Guj.St.Fe.Ch(2) INE026A01025
  A 542812 Gujarat Fluoroch(1) INE09N301011
  A 539336 Gujarat Gas Ltd(2 INE844O01030
  A 533248 Gujarat Pipavav INE517F01014
  A 538567 Gulf Oil Lubri(2) INE635Q01029
  A 541019 H.G.Infra Eng. INE926X01010
  A 533162 Hathway Cable(2) INE982F01036
  A 531531 Hatsun Agro(1) INE473B01035 Hatsun Milk
  A 517354 Havells Ind(1) INE176B01034
  A 508486 Hawkins Cook INE979B01015
  A 532281 HCL Techno(2) INE860A01027
  A 541729 HDFC Asset Manag(5) INE127D01025
  A 500180 HDFC Bank(2) INE040A01026
  A 540777 HDFC Insurance Co INE795G01014 HDFC Standar
  A 500010 HDFC(2) INE001A01036
  A 539787 Healthcare Global Ent INE075I01017
  A 509631 HEG Ltd. INE545A01016
  A 500292 Heideberg Cement INE578A01017 Mys Cement
  A 519552 Heritage Food(5) INE978A01027
  A 500182 Hero Motocorp(2) INE158A01026 Hero Honda(2
  A 524669 Hester Biosciences INE782E01017 Hester Pharm
  A 532129 Hexaware Tec(2) INE093A01033 Aptech Ltd.
  A 524735 Hikal Ltd(2) INE475B01022
  A 509675 HIL Ltd INE557A01011 Hyd.Indus
  A 500183 Him.Fut.Comm(1) INE548A01028
  A 500184 Himadri Spec(1) INE019C01026 Himadri Chem
  A 514043 Himatsing Seid(5) INE049A01027
  A 500185 Hind.Const(1) INE549A01026
  A 513599 Hind.Copper (5) INE531E01026
  A 500186 Hind.Oil Exp INE345A01011
  A 500104 Hind.Petrol INE094A01015
  A 500696 Hind.Unilever(1) INE030A01027 Hind.Lever(1
  A 500188 Hind.Zinc(2) INE267A01025
  A 500440 Hindalco(1) INE038A01020
  A 541154 Hindustan Aeronautics INE066F01012
  A 522064 Honda India Power Prod INE634A01018 Honda Siel
  A 517174 Honeywell INE671A01010 Tata Honeywl
  A 540530 Housing & Urban Dev INE031A01017
  A 509820 Huntamaki India L INE275B01026 Huntamaki PP
  A 532174 ICICI Bankin(2) INE090A01021
  A 540716 ICICI Lombard INE765G01017
  A 540133 ICICI Prudent Life INE726G01019
  A 541179 ICICI Securit(5) INE763G01038
  A 532835 Icra Ltd INE725G01011
  A 500116 IDBI Ltd. INE008A01015 Industrial D
  A 539437 IDFC FIRST BANK L INE092T01019 IDFC BANK LT
  A 532659 Idfc Ltd INE043D01016
  A 505726 IFB Ind.Ltd. INE559A01017
  A 500106 IFCI Ltd. INE039A01010
  A 517380 Igarshi Mot INE188B01013 CG Igarshi M
  A 532636 IIFL Holding (2) INE530B01024 India Infoli
  A 542773 IIFL Securities(2) INE489L01022
  A 542772 IIFL Wealth Manag(2) INE466L01020
  A 500201 Ind.Glycols INE560A01015
  A 504741 Ind.Hume Pip(2) INE323C01030
  A 530005 India Cement INE383A01012
  A 532189 India Touris INE353K01014
  A 535789 Indiabul Hous.F(2) INE148I01020
  A 532832 Indiabul Real(2) INE069I01010
  A 542726 IndiaMart Intermesh INE933S01016
  A 532814 Indian Bank INE562A01011
  A 540750 Indian Energy Exc(1) INE022Q01020
  A 500850 Indian Hotel(1) INE053A01029
  A 530965 Indian Oil Corp INE242A01010
  A 532388 Indian Over. INE565A01014
  A 521016 Indo Count(2) INE483B01026
  A 532612 Indoco Rem(2) INE873D01024
  A 541336 Indostar Capital Fin INE896L01010
  A 532514 Indra Gas(2) INE203G01027
  A 534816 Indus Towers INE121J01017 Bharti Infra
  A 532187 Indusind Bnk INE095A01012
  A 539807 Infibeam Avenues(1) INE483S01020 Infibeam Inc
  A 532777 Info Edge INE663F01024
  A 500209 Infosys Ltd(5) INE009A01021
  A 500210 Ingersoll INE177A01018
  A 532706 Inox Leisure INE312H01016
  A 532851 Insecticides INEO7OI01018
  A 538835 Intellect Design(5) INE306R01017
  A 539448 InterGlobe Aviation INE646L01027
  A 524164 IOL Chemical & Pharma INE485C01011 IndsOrganic
  A 500214 ION Exchange INE570A01014
  A 524494 Ipca Lab.Ltd (2) INE571A01020
  A 532947 IRB Infrastruct INE821I01014
  A 541956 Ircon Inter.Ltd(2 INE962Y01021
  A 542830 IRCTC Railway Cateri INE335Y01020
  A 533033 ISGEC Heavy Eng.( INE858B01029
  A 500875 Itc Ltd(1) INE154A01025
  A 509496 Itd Cement(1) INE686A01026
  A 523610 ITI Ltd. INE248A01017
  A 532209 J&K Bank(1) INE168A01041
  A 532940 J.Kumar Infrapro(5) INE576I01022
  A 532705 Jagran Praka(2) INE199G01027
  A 512237 Jai Corp Ltd(1) INE070D01027
  A 500219 Jain Irri(2) INE175A01038
  A 532532 Jaipra.Associt(2) INE455F01025
  A 520051 Jamna Auto(1) INE039C01032
  A 506943 Jb Chemical(2) INE572A01028
  A 500227 Jind.Polys INE197D01010
  A 500378 Jind.Saw(2) INE324A01024 Saw Pipes
  A 539597 Jind.Stain(His)(1) INE455T01018
  A 532508 Jind.Stainl(2) INE220G01021 Jsl Stainles
  A 532286 Jind.Steel Pow(1) INE749A01030
  A 532644 Jk Cement INE823G01014
  A 500380 JK Laksh.Cem(5) INE786A01032
  A 532162 JK Paper INE789E01012 Central Pulp
  A 530007 JK Tyre & Ind(2) INE573A01042
  A 523405 JM Financial(1) INE780C01023
  A 522263 JMC Projects(2) INE890A01024
  A 523398 Johnson Controls- INE782A01015 Hitachi Home
  A 532642 JSW Holdings Ltd INE824G01012 Jindal South
  A 500228 JSW Steel(1) INE019A01038
  A 520057 JTEKT India Ltd(1 INE643A01035 Sona Koyo St
  A 533155 Jubilant Foodwork INE797F01012
  A 530019 Jubilant Pharmova INE700A01033 Jubilant Lif
  A 535648 Just Dial Ltd INE599M01018
  A 532926 Jyothy Lab.(1) INE668F01031 Jyothy Labor
  A 500233 Kajaria Cer(1) INE217B01028
  A 532268 Kale Consul. INE793A01012
  A 522287 Kalpa.Power(2) INE220B01022
  A 500235 Kalyani Stel(5) INE907A01026
  A 532468 Kama Holdings Ltd INE411F01010 Srf Polymers
  A 500165 Kansai Nerolec(1) INE531A01024
  A 532652 Karnatka Bank INE614B01018 590002
  A 532899 Kaveri Seed (2) INE455I01029
  A 532714 Kec Intern(2) INE389H01022
  A 517569 Kei Indust(2) INE878B01027
  A 505890 Kenna Metal W INE717A01029
  A 532967 Kiri Industries INE415I01015 Kiridyes & C
  A 533293 Kirl.OilEng(2) INE146L01010
  A 521248 Kitex Garment(1) INE602G01020
  A 532942 KNR Constr.(2) INE634I01029
  A 532924 Kolte-Patil Dep INE094I01018
  A 500247 Kotak Bank(5) INE237A01028
  A 542651 Kpit Techno.Ltd INE04I401011
  A 532889 KPR.Mill ltd(1 INE930H01031
  A 530813 KRBL Ltd.(1) INE001B01026 Khushi Ram B
  A 500249 KSB Ltd INE999A01015 KSB Pumps
  A 533519 L&T Fin.Holding INE498L01015
  A 540115 L&T Techno.Service(2) INE010V01017
  A 534690 Laksh.Vilas Bank INE694C01018
  A 500252 Lakshmi Mach(10) INE269B01029
  A 526947 La-opala Rg(2) INE059D01020
  A 540005 Larsen & Toubro Inf(1) INE214T01019
  A 500510 Larsen Tubro(2) INE018A01030
  A 540222 Laurus Labs Ltd(2 INE947Q01028
  A 541233 Lemon Tree Hotels INE970X01018
  A 500250 LG Balkrishnan INE337A01034 Lg Balabros
  A 500253 LIC Hous.Fin(2) INE115A01026
  A 531633 Lincoln Pharm INE405C01035
  A 523457 Linde india Ltd. INE473A01011 BOC (i) Ltd.
  A 532783 Lt Foods Ltd(1) INE818H01020
  A 500257 Lupin Ltd.(2) INE326A01037 Lupin Chem
  A 539542 Lux Indus.Ltd(2) INE150G01020
  A 532720 M&M Finance(2) INE774D01024
  A 500266 Mah.Scooter INE288A01013
  A 500265 Maha.Seamless(5) INE271B01025
  A 539957 Mahanagar Gas Ltd INE002S01010
  A 532756 Mahind CIE Automo INE536H01010 Mahind Forgi
  A 532313 Mahind Lifes Dev INE813A01018 Mahindra Ges
  A 500520 Mahindra & Mah(5) INE101A01026
  A 533088 Mahindra Holidays INE998I01010
  A 540768 Mahindra Logistics INE766P01016
  A 531213 Manappuram Fin(2) INE522D01027 Manappuram G
  A 502157 Mangalam Cem INE347A01017
  A 531642 Marico (1) INE196A01026
  A 524404 Marksans(1) INE750C01026 Tasc Pharma.
  A 532500 Maruti Suzuki(5) INE585B01010 Maruti Udyog
  A 540749 MAS Financial Serv INE348L01012
  A 523704 Mastek Ltd(5) INE759A01021
  A 500271 Max Fin.Serv.(2) INE180A01020 Max India(2)
  A 539981 Max India Ltd(2) INE153U01017
  A 522249 Mayur Uniquo(5) INE040D01038
  A 532865 Meghmani Organ(1) INE974H01013
  A 542650 Metropolis Health(2) INE112L01020
  A 538962 Minda Corpo.Lt(2) INE842C01021
  A 532539 Minda Ind(2) INE405E01023
  A 532819 Mindtree LTD INE018I01017
  A 513377 Mineral&Metl(1) INE123F01029 MMTC Ltd
  A 541195 Mishra Dhatu Nigam INE099Z01011
  A 533286 MOIL LTD INE490G01020
  A 533080 Mold-Tek Packaging INE893J01011 MoldTek Plas
  A 524084 Monsanto (I) INE274B01011 Monsanto Che
  A 500288 Morepen Lab(2) INE083A01026
  A 517334 Motherson Sumi(1) INE775A01035
  A 532892 Motilal OswalF(1) INE338I01027
  A 526299 Mphasis Bfl INE356A01018 BFL Software
  A 500290 MRF Ltd. INE883A01011
  A 500109 MRPL INE103A01014
  A 542597 MSTC Limited INE255X01014
  A 534091 Multi Commodty.Exch INE745G01035
  A 533398 Muthoot Finance INE414G01012
  A 539551 Narayana Hrudayalaya INE410P01011
  A 523630 Nat.Fertiliser INE870D01012
  A 526371 Nat.Mineral(1) INE584A01023
  A 500298 Nat.Peroxide INE585A01020
  A 524816 Natco Pharma INE987B01018
  A 537291 Nath Bio-Genes(I) INE448G01010
  A 532234 National Alum(5) INE139A01034
  A 513023 Nava Bharat V(2) INE725A01022
  A 532504 Navin Fluori(2) INE048G01026
  A 508989 Navneet Education(2) INE060A01024 Navneet Publ
  A 534309 NBCC(India) Lt(1) INE095N01031
  A 500294 NCC Ltd(2) INE868B01028 Nagar.Constr
  A 502168 NCL Ind. INE732C01016
  A 542665 Neogen Chemicals INE136S01016
  A 505355 NESCO LTD INE317F01027 New Std.Eng.
  A 500790 Nestle (I)Ltd. INE239A01016
  A 532798 Network18 Med(5) INE870H01013 Network18 Fi
  A 524558 Neuland Lab. INE794A01010
  A 540900 Newgen Softw.Tech INE619B01017
  A 533098 NHPC LIMITED INE848E01016
  A 500304 NIIT Ltd.(2) INE161A01038
  A 523385 Nilkamal Pls INE310A01015
  A 540767 Nippon Life India Asset INE298J01013 Reliance Nip
  A 500307 Nirlon INE910A01012
  A 513683 NLC India Ltd INE589A01014 Neyveli Lign
  A 500730 NOCIL INE163A01018
  A 500672 Novartis India(5) INE234A01025 Hind.ciba
  A 530367 Nrb Bearing(2) INE349A01021
  A 532555 NTPC Ltd INE733E01010
  A 531209 Nucle.Soft E INE096B01018
  A 533273 Oberoi Realty INE093I01010
  A 533106 OIL INDIA LTD INE274J01014
  A 532880 Omaxe Ltd INE800H01010
  A 500312 ONGC Corp.(5) INE213A01029
  A 532466 Oracle Financ(5) INE881D01027 Iflex Solu(5
  A 535754 Orient Cement(1) INE876N01018
  A 541301 Orient Electric INE142Z01019
  A 506579 Orient.Carb. INE321D01016
  A 500315 Oriental Bank INE141A01014
  A 532827 Page Industr INE761H01022
  A 532900 Paisalo Digital INE420C01042 SE Investmen
  A 531349 Panacea Biot(1) INE922B01023
  A 539889 Parag Milk Foods INE883N01014
  A 531120 Patel Engg.(1) INE244B01030
  A 534809 PC Jeweller Ltd INE785M01013
  A 533179 Persistent System INE262H01013
  A 532522 Petronet Lng INE347G01014
  A 500680 Pfizer Ltd. INE182A01018
  A 506590 Phil.Carbon(2) INE602A01023
  A 503100 Phoenix Mill(2) INE211B01039
  A 523642 PI Indus.Ltd(1) INE603J01030
  A 500331 Pidilite Ind(1) INE318A01026
  A 539883 Pilani Inv.&Ind INE417C01014
  A 500302 Piramal Enter(2) INE140A01024 Piramal Heal
  A 540173 PNB Housing Fin INE572E01012
  A 539150 PNC Infratech (2) INE195J01029
  A 531768 Poly Medicur(5) INE205C01021
  A 542652 Polycab India INE455K01017
  A 524051 Polyplex INE633B01018
  A 524000 Poonawalla Fincor INE511C01022 Magma Fincor
  A 532810 Power Finan INE134E01011
  A 532898 Power Grid Corp. INE752E01010
  A 539302 Power Mech Proj. INE211R01019
  A 506022 Prakash Ind. INE603A01013
  A 540724 Prataap Snacks (5) INE393P01035
  A 533274 Prestige EstatePr INE811K01011
  A 540293 Pricol Limited(1) INE726V01018
  A 542907 Prince Pipes&Fittings INE689W01016
  A 500338 Prism Johnson INE010A01011 Prism Cement
  A 530117 Privi Speciality INE959A01019 Fairchem Spe
  A 500126 Procter & Gamble INE199A01012 Merck Ltd
  A 500459 Procter&gamb INE179A01014
  A 540544 PSP Projects Ltd INE488V01015
  A 532524 PTC India INE877F01012
  A 533344 PTC India Financ INE560K01014
  A 532461 Punj.Nat.Bank(2) INE160A01022
  A 532689 Pvr Ltd INE191H01014
  A 539978 Quess Corp Ltd INE615P01015
  .
  .
  .
  A 532648 Yes Bank ltd(2) INE528G01027
  A 505537 Zee Enter(1) INE256A01028 Zee Telefilm
  A 504067 Zensar Tech.(2) INE520A01027
  A 531335 Zydus Wellness INE768C01010 Carnation He
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: If need to scrap the data, then what is the need to use selenium here? Why BeautifulSoup or other scrapping is not used?

Comment: @QualityMatters Feel free to checkout my my previous answers on Selenium vs BS. In some cases Selenium is best suited where as in some cases it's advantage BS.

Answer (score -2):

There is a frame in this site. That's why it is throwing no such element.
You need to first switch to that frame. Then try to get innerHTML.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
String table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Table: "+ table);
```

**Output:** Your output will be like this. Now from this, you can extract the values.

Table:

```
  <tbody><tr bgcolor="#6699cc" style="color:white;">
  <th width="8%" class="specialTDBig">Group</th>
  <th width="10%" class="specialTDBig">BSE Code</th>
  
  <th width="33%" class="specialTDBig">BSE Name</th>
  
  <th width="16%" class="specialTDBig">ISINNO</th>
  <th width="20%" class="specialTDBig">Old Name</th>
  
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="specialTDBig">A</td>
  <td class="specialTDBig">523395</td>
  
  <td class="specialTDBig">3M India Ltd       </td>

  
  <td class="specialTDBig">INE470A01017</td>
```

Comment: He just needs to switch inside the frame before interacting to element. That's the reason he was getting the exception which he posted in question.

Comment: Post a new question for how to store values inside panda dataframe from webpage with selenium? Else, this question will be misleading.

Comment: I have added edit and it will be soon out by community.